# Histogram generator

Tags: c++, c++11

This is some code to generate a histogram (or maybe: histochart) in the form of a simple list of words and how many of that word were found in the input file. It accepts an input file name on the command line. For our purpose, a "word" consists of English letters and/or the apostrophe (e.g., so `we're` is treated as one word, not two). Case insensitive comparison must be used, so (for example) `Build` and `build` are treated as equal (and the result should show the words entirely in lower case).

All other characters (digits, punctuation other than apostrophe, etc.) are to be ignored.

The result is to be sorted in inverse order by frequency (i.e., the words that occurred the most often listed first).

It also uses (requires) a set of stop words (stored in a file named "stopwords.txt") that are to be ignored. This is intended to hold words like "a", "an", "the", "am", "are", "is", "was", "were", etc., that are similar to punctuation--necessary for grammatical sentences, but irrelevant to meaning, so their presence in the histogram would just add noise.

```
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

typedef const std::pair<int, std::string> ytype;

namespace std {
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, ytype const &y) {
        return std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << y.second << "\t" << y.first;
    }
}

std::string tolower(std::string in) {
    for (auto &c : in) {
        c = std::tolower(unsigned char(c));
    }
    return in;
}

class alpha_only : public std::ctype<char> {
public:
    mask const *get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype<char>::mask>  table(table_size, (mask)space);
        std::fill(table.begin() + 'a', table.begin()+'z', (mask)alpha);
        std::fill(table.begin() + 'A', table.begin()+'Z', (mask)alpha);
        table['\''] = (mask)alpha;  // an apostrophe will also be considered part of a word

        return &table[0];
    }
    alpha_only(size_t refs = 0) : std::ctype<char>(get_table(), false, refs) { }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: hist <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);

    input.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new alpha_only));

    std::map<std::string, int> counts;

    std::ifstream stop("stopwords.txt");

    std::set<std::string> stopwords{
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stop),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
    };

    std::string word;
    while (input >> word) {
        word = tolower(word);
        if (stopwords.find(word) == stopwords.end())
            ++counts[word];
    }

    std::multimap<int, std::string> words;

    for (auto const &v : counts)
        words.emplace(v.second, v.first);

    std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<ytype>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Fix the bug

The `operator<<` looks fine except that it always prints to `std::cout` rather than to the passed `std::ostream &os`, which is an obvious and easily corrected error.

### Use only necessary `#include`s

The code has this line:

```
#include <vector>
```

but no `std::vector` is used in the code.  That `#include` can be eliminated.

### Take care when casting

The code currently contains this line:

```
c = std::tolower(unsigned char(c));
```

which I assume is intended to be a cast, but it has two problems.  The first is that it's not actually valid cast syntax.  If it were a single word, such as `unsigned` or `char` it would work, but multiword type names are not allowed in that context.  See the note for the [functional cast expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) on cppreference.  The second problem with it is that it converts a `char` to an `unsigned char` (because `std::string` is defined as `std::basic_string<char>`).  There's not really a need for that since `c` is already guaranteed to be of a type that `tolower` can handle.  Either eliminate the cast or see the next suggestion.

### Consider an alternative approach

The use of a `std::facet` only addresses part of the problem.  That is, it only categorizes the characters appropriately but it doesn't lowercase the result.  A more direct approach would be to use [`std::char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) which allow for both operations very simply.  First, here's a new trait:

```
struct lowercase_traits : public std::char_traits<char> {
    static constexpr char_type to_char_type( int_type c ) {
        if (std::isalpha(c) || c == '\'') 
            return std::tolower(c);
        return not_eof(c) ? ' ' : eof();
    }
};
```

This overloads only the single `to_char_type` static function and simply returns the lowercase version of each character *or* a space, depending on if it's in the desired set or not.  Note that `EOF` is also specifically handled by the final `return` statement.

For convenience, we'll use some `typedef`s but I've put them in a separate namespace for neatness where possible:

```
namespace coffin {
    typedef std::basic_ifstream<char, lowercase_traits> ifstream;
    typedef std::basic_string<char, lowercase_traits> string;
    typedef const std::pair<int, std::string> ytype;
}
namespace std {
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, coffin::ytype const &y) {
            return os << std::left << std::setw(20) << y.second << "\t" << y.first;
    }
}
```

Now all that remains is to read in this new type of string from this new type of `ifstream`:

```
int main() 
{
    using namespace coffin;

    ifstream input("foo.txt");

    std::map<string, int> counts;
    ifstream stop("stopwords.txt");

    std::set<string> stopwords{
            std::istream_iterator<string, char, lowercase_traits>(stop),
            std::istream_iterator<string, char, lowercase_traits>()
    };

    string word;
    while (input >> word) {
            if (stopwords.find(word) == stopwords.end())
                    ++counts[word];
    }
```

The final part of the program is almost identical to the original with a small tweak to convert the lowercase string to plain `std::string`:

```
    std::multimap<int, std::string> words; 

    for (auto const &v : counts) {
        words.emplace(v.second, v.first.c_str());
    }

    std::copy(words.rbegin(), words.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<ytype>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Optimizing the algorithm

All tests were done on a 4.7mb file containing a copy of the history of the US and a copy of a medical manual; around 1400 pages worth of content).

Timings are an average of executing one single run through the file 10 times. The code was compiled under VC++2015 x64.

Here's a link to the test program; simply use your own files where appropriate.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28907bc68796a0bf

### Better containers for lookup

You're using a `std::map<>` in order to count word occurrence. You should use a `std::unordered_map<>` as it provies amortized O(1) lookup. This is highly beneficial for large documents. We replace:

`std::map<std::string, int> counts;`

With:

`std::unordered_map<std::string, int> counts;`

This reduced runtime from 524ms to 352ms.

---

Similarly, you're using a `std::set<>` in order to find stopwords in O(logn) time. You should use a `std::unordered_set<>` as it provides amortized O(1) lookup. We replace:

`std::set<std::string> stopwords{ ... };`

With:

`std::unordered_set<std::string> stopwords{ ... };`

I've tested this with the following stopwords.txt file:

> a an the am are is was were and then for I

This reduced runtime from 352ms to 325ms.

---

### Optimize `tolower()`

We can cut out execution time by directly modifying the string reference instead of copying it in. Thus, this function:

```
std::string tolower(std::string in) {
    for (auto &c : in) {
        c = std::tolower(unsigned char(c));
    }
    return in;
}
```

Can be implemented like so:

```
void tolower(std::string& in) {
    for (auto &c : in) {
        c = std::tolower(unsigned char(c));
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fde03e878f21d91)

---

Furthermore, since your character table only uses ASCII characters, this provides a bigger speed boost than calling `std::tolower()` for every individual character:

```
void tolower_ref( std::string& in )
{
    static constexpr int diff{ 'a' - 'A' };
    for ( auto &c : in )
        if ( c < 'a' && c != '\'' )
            c += diff;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2db87c2e194bc46a)

This reduced runtime from 325ms to 274ms.

---

## Conclusion

By applying a small couple of changes, the speed of the algorithm was increased by ~50%.